# Click radio button then show submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to make a click to show submit button using radio button. But i have one question..

I have created this **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/YPvgWq)** from *codepen.io*

In this demo you can see there is a six radio button. (for example:)The first tree radio button is for xx, and second tree radio button is for yy .

I made a submit button for the two parts.When you change any one of the three radio buttons in the first part then the first submit button is automatically display:block; but at the same time the second part submit button is `display:block;` i don't want to it.

I want to make when first part radio buttons clicked then first part submit button `display:block;` also same think for second part.

How can i do that anyone can help me in this regard ?

HTML

```
<div class="container">

  <div class="radio_wrp">
  <input type="radio" name="x" class="yesno rdbtn"/>Yes
  <input type="radio" name="x" class="yesno rdbtn"/>No
  <input type="radio" name="x" class="yesno rdbtn" checked/>Maybe
  </div>
  <div class="submitbutton"><input type="submit" class="first"></div>
</div>
<div class="container">

  <div class="radio_wrp">
  <input type="radio" name="y" class="yesno rdbtn" checked/>Yes
  <input type="radio" name="y" class="yesno rdbtn"/>No
  <input type="radio" name="y" class="yesno rdbtn"/>Maybe
  </div>
  <div class="submitbutton"><input type="submit" class="first"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
  width:500px;
  margin:0px auto;
  margin-top:50px;
}
.yesno {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  width: 30px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 14px;
  outline: 0;
  background: #9da6b0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.15s ease-in-out;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.yesno:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 11px;
  position: relative;
  top: 3px;
  left: 3px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.15s ease-in-out;
}
.yesno:checked {
  background: #529ecc;
}
.yesno:checked:after {
  left: 13px;
}
.radio_wrp {
  float:left;
  width:500px;
  height:auto;
}
.submitbutton {
  float:left;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
}
.first {display:none;}
.second{display:none;}
```

javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.rdbtn').click(function(){
            $('.first').show();
        });
    });
```

> Note: I know if i change the class name for second part submit button
>   is not display:block; when clicked first part radio buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly sure what you need but maybe this will point you in the right direction:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.rdbtn').click(function(){
       $('.first').hide(); //if you want to hide one that is already shown
       $(this).closest('.container').find('.first').show();           
    });
});
```

[Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/raKEWR)

It uses `$(this)` to get the clicked radio, then uses it as an anchor point. It uses `closest`, which works up the way to find the parent `container` and then `finds` the button you want inside only that container.

Comment: Thanks for this answer it is what i want to do. Can i make it like this for cancel. Please click this [DEMO](http://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/YPvgWq)

Comment: No worries.  you can add the first class to your 'cancel' button so that they show\hide as a pair if that's what you mean.

Comment: So you add your answer `$('.first').hide();` i want to make it if user click `.cancel` button then close submit button. I've already added a cancel class. Please click this: [DEMO](http://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/YPvgWq)

Answer (score 5):

Checkbout this answer should help you..
http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/VFJGD/

```
    <input type="radio" name="TermLease" value="No" onclick="TermLeaseMonths.disabled=true"/>No
<input type="radio" name="TermLease" value="Yes"  onclick="TermLeaseMonths.disabled=false"/>Yes | 
How many months:<input type="hidden" name="TermLeaseMonths"  value="0" />
<input type="submit" name="TermLeaseMonths" id="TermLeaseMonths" size="1" disabled="disabled"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please can you find `closest('.container')` like

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.rdbtn').click(function(){
        $(this).closest('.container').find('.first').show() ; 
    });
});
```

[JSFIDDLE Link check here](http://jsfiddle.net/higunjan/2qqnmh3g/3/)

Answer (score 0):

With using parents() also it can be done:

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('.rdbtn').click(function(){
        $('.first').hide(); 
        $(this).parents('.container').find('.first').show();  
     });
   });
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/q5L260x6/)

Comment: This is same answer like @davy

Comment: @innovation He used .closest() but I used .parents()

Comment: oh sorry i notice it now.

Comment: @innovation FYI  ".parent() is basically just a wrapper for the DOM call .parentNode. It's very quick and efficient, since it's essentially a single call to a browser built-in".

Comment: @innovation not mention ji